# How should I handle caching?

Tags: javascript, java, caching

I have a SPA application which is written in Websocket, Polymer, ES6, HTML5. This is served by a Jetty 9 backend which is packaged as a runnable jar with absolutely everything in the JAR.

I'd like to have it such that when a new version of the JAR is deployed, I push a message down to the client to force it to do a cache-less refresh of all the resources.

I have a custom `HttpServlet` to serve my SPA so I can handle the URL "rewriting":

```
private static final Path ROOT = getDevelopmentWebRoot();

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String requestPath = req.getPathInfo();

    if (requestPath.equals("/")) {
        requestPath = "index.html";
    } else {
        requestPath = requestPath.substring(1);
    }

    Path resource = ROOT.resolve(requestPath);

    resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=31536000");
    resp.setContentType(MimeTypes.getDefaultMimeByExtension(resource.toString()));

    try {
        Files.copy(resource, resp.getOutputStream());
    } catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
        Files.copy(ROOT.resolve("index.html"), resp.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

I guess my question is, how can I force a cache-less refresh in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a cache with the headers "Last-Modified" and "Cache-Control"  with "must-revalidate". This should force the browser to do a "If-Modified-Since" request everytime.

Then in your frontend you can just reload the page every X seconds, and if nothing as been modified you should get it from the cache (instantaneous) else it will load the new page.

I haven't tested it but I think it should work like you want it to.

Comment: Thanks - this is what I have gone for - for now. It's not ideal as there is still a request that goes out to the server everytime there is a page load, but it will do for now :)